# How to query for boolean property with Spring CrudRepository?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring `CrudRepository` for database queries. How can I create a method signature (not writing SQL select statement myself) for a boolean property?

The following does not work:

```
class MyEntity {
       private boolean active;
}


interface MyEntityRepository implements CrudRepository<MyEntity, Long> {
   List<MyEntity> findActive(); //or also: findNotActive();
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I would do:

```
interface MyEntityRepository implements CrudRepository<MyEntity, Long> {
   List<MyEntity> findByActive(Boolean active);
}
```

Then the service layer would be

```
public class MyEntityServiceImpl implements MyEntityService{


   public List<MyEntity> findActive() {
      return myEntityRepository.findByActive(true);
   }
}
```

**UPDATE**

As pointed out by @OliverGierke you could simplify your repository even more by doing:

```
interface MyEntityRepository implements CrudRepository<MyEntity, Long> {
   List<MyEntity> findByActiveTrue(); //you could also use findByActiveFalse
}
```

For all the supported keywords you should see the section

> Query creation

of the [reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html)

Comment: ok that's probably way better than tying the result actually to a boolean value directly.

Comment: @membersound Probably yes!

Comment: Great answer, you might wanna add the option to directly use `findByActiveTrue()` in case you don't want to supply the parameter for each call.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Olivergierke! That's a great suggestion! I will update the answer once I get to a computer